# Servlets are not running

Tags: java, servlets

I am getting following  Exception report while running servlets. what is the problem?

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class servlets.Nm or a class it depends on
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlets.Nm
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 logs.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>LoadImage</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>FileUpload</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileUpload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.FileUpload</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUpload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileUpload</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Checking</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Checking</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.Checking</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Checking</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Checking</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It looks like you listed a servlet in your `web.xml` whose class is `servlets.Nm`, but you didn't actually have that class in your `war`. Check your package names.

Comment: Can you post the web.xml and your servlet as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is no class in your war's WEB-INF/classes folder. or in a jar in WEB-INF/lib
please manually inspect your war file to see if this class exists.

Comment: Problem got solved.There was a corrupted jar file in lib folder.Thanks